# Independent random generations in Javascript / p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In P5.js, I often have to write more than one line of random in order to get independent random generation such as :

```js
random();
random();
random();

// or 
a = random();
b = random();
c = random();

//etc
```

is there any alternative code(s) in p5.js or javascript that can perform the same/similar generations and so the code efficiency can be improve?
Thanks

Comment: What do those calls of `random` go into? An array? Various variables? Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: I usually then will put the values into functions such as ellipse();, circle() or other shapes

Comment: Please elaborate; the [docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/randomSeed) say that random() already gives different results when the program runs multiple times, so what exactly is the thing you're trying to prevent/accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

If you're putting random numbers into an array, you can do it concisely with `Array.from`:

```js
const random = () => Math.random();

const arr = Array.from({ length: 3 }, random);
console.log(arr);
```

You can do the same sort of thing for multiple separate variables by destructuring:

```js
const random = () => Math.random();

const [a, b, c] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, random);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

If you need to call `random` with certain parameters, then:

```js
const random = (low, high) => Math.floor((high - low) * Math.random()) + low;

const [a, b, c] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => random(1, 4));
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather not perform random calculations within draw() then you could generate an array of pre-calculated random numbers in setup. When you need a random number you just grab one from the array.

```
let rndListLength = 100;
let rndNums;

function setup() {  
  rndNums = [...Array(rndListLength).keys()].map(a => random());

  // Show complete list
  console.log(rndNums);

  // Show number 17 in list 
  // (remember the first array index is always 0)
  console.log(rndNums[16]);
}
```